# SDF Volumetric Morphing Noise in Density Problem

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, volumetrics

I've been following the tutorial you can find below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ubfb2K6mL0

Currently I am experiencing some sort of noise/artifacting problem near bounding boxes where I cannot express or describe where it is coming from and in need of a direction or description of problem to understand. Using following graphs;

Main:
[image: Main]

Res:
[image: Res]

CorrectSDF:
[image: CorrectSDF]

Outside:
[image: Outside]

Resulting with (Volume basis is aligned inside the bounding plane):
[image: Result]

Duplicated Original Mesh (Found over SketchFab):
[image]

Note: While responding, keep in mind that I am experienced in game production as in technical aspect for ~14 years, mostly a software engineer and game designer, have beef with various techniques, 3DsMax, Maya and Blender, basic shader programming yet never worked with volumetrics before.

Thanks